# Finding substring of string

Tags: c++

So, I'm just starting out this C++ course and we are doing strings now. For this assignment, what my professor wants me to do is to find a string within a string and to print it out and at a position. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "Please enter a phrase: " << endl;
string phrase;
getline(cin, phrase);

cout << "Please enter a possible substring of the phrase: " << endl;
string phrase_2;
getline(cin, phrase_2);

string pos = phrase.substr(phrase_2);
cout << phrase_2 << "was found at position " << pos << endl;
return 0;

}
```

I have tried multiple hours trying to get the code to print out the position. This might be totally wrong and I apologize for that, but if you could help me out, I would appreciate it.

Comment: You are looking for `string::find`, as in `size_t pos = phrase.find(phrase_2);`. `substr()` does something different (look it up in the documentation to find out what).

Comment: You should also get used to **always** checking your inputs after you tried to read something, e.g., `if (std::getline(std::cin, phrase)) { ... }`.

Comment: What were you doing for hours? You need to use a website such as http://cppreference.com to decide what functions to use, and what they do.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the helper functions? My professors would most likely want me to write custom logic for this kind of assignment, with loops and such.

Comment: Thank you Igor for the help. We were not taught about size_t so I'm sure there was another way to do it. Regardless, thanks for the help. I now got it to work.

Comment: How does your code even compile? `std::string`'s `substr` function requires one or two `size_t` parameters, not a `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [std::string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) to get the position of a sub string within a string:

Using your code as an example:

```
int main ()
{
  cout << "Please enter a phrase: \n";
  string phrase;
  getline(cin, phrase);

  cout << "Please enter a possible substring of the phrase: \n";
  string phrase_2;
  getline(cin, phrase_2);

  std::size_t position = phrase.find(phrase_2);
  if (position != std::string::npos)
    std::cout << phrase_2 << " was found at position " << position << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @jons34yp, why did you replace the std::endl for the '\n'?

Comment: `<< std::endl` is roughly equivalent to `<< '\n' << std::flush`. In this case, a flush unnecessarily reduces performance.

Comment: Not necessarily @jons34yp, in many implementations the standard output is line-buffered, so '\n' causes a flush anyway. Unless you explicitly say otherwise (std::cout.sync_with_stdio(false)). Also you could have hinted that as a comment instead of an edit, so everyone can benefit from the insight.

Answer (score 0):

[Google is your friend](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%20malloc&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#q=c%2b%2b%20substring%20position&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial)...

Instead of

```
string pos = phrase.substr(phrase_2);
```

You should use

```
size_t pos = phrase.find(phrase_2);
```